# How to delete a row from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql database I have three rows I want to delete the row sexualintercourse (make it equel to null) where id =2 for example I tried using :

```
ALTER TABLE Normal DROP COLUMN sexualintercourse WHERE id=2
```

But I got an error

Comment: if you want to delete the particular row of a table use this DELETE FROM Normal WHERE id = '2';

Comment: `delete from tableName where id=2`

Comment: Yes with a condition

Comment: @hassan I thik that deletes all the rows but I want to delete a particular one

Comment: @Amal this will delete row that have id = 2

Comment: @Amal are you want to set NULL in sexualintercourse column where id = 2 ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Alter table .. drop column` is for deleting a column not a row.
What you Need is `DELETE FROM table where id=2` or `UPDATE table set sexualintercourse = null where id=2` if you only want to remove the value of the column for id =2 it is not really clear in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM Normal WHERE id =2;
```

It will delete all rows in Normal table where id will be equal to 2.

**Or if you want to update sexualintercourse column with NULL then use below query.**

```
UPDATE Normal SET sexualintercourse = NULL  WHERE id = 2;
```